# project Setup with code access to all

Tags: java, tortoisesvn

I just created an application and now i want my application code to be accessible to all my team. i want to place it in a repository with my team having access to the repo.
I am using Java and apache tomcat 6. I know that there is something like Tortoise SVN.
Can you guyz please help!

Comment: Why is there a downvote for this? <br> did i ask something wrong??

Answer (score 0):

set up a git repository.

http://git-scm.com/

there are some tutorials for a set up.
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository (for example)

for eclipse:
http://www.eclipse.org/resources/resource.php?id=528

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to learn about version control systems:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software

I can recommend:

- Subversion (client-server; used by many companies; 'svn' as in TortoiseSVN stands for Subversion)
- Mercurial (distributed; more modern than Subversion; used e.g. by OpenJDK)
- Git (distributed; more modern than Subversion) (I haven't used this a lot, but it's qutie popular as well)